# About including svg into LaTeX or workaround

Tags: conversion, svg

I am looking for a way to include `svg` image into the LaTeX. I know there are some discussion on this topic before and I think LaTeX just don't support SVG directly. I read few posts here and people suggest to use Inkscape to edit the `svg` and save it as LaTeX-`pdf`-`svg` then use command `\includesvg` to insert the image. But since I have too many `svg` created before and it is no way for me to edit them one by one with Inkscape. I am looking for other workaround (I mean still keep it as scalable vector image supported by LaTeX). The first way I can think of is to convert the `svg` with imagemagick to `eps`, which can be done with script. However, I don't know why, the converted `eps` is all black and all detail are gone. So besides imagemagick, any free code do you recommend to convert `svg` to `eps` in Linux? or do you have any other suggestion on inserting `svg` to LaTeX?

p.s. The system is opened to a group of people and they can generate and upload their SVG. So before I insert all those images into LaTeX, I have to convert them into LaTeX-supporting format. But the server doesn't have inkscape installed, I am looking for other converter.

Comment: You can convert svg to pdf using inkscape's command line (therefore, no need to edit them one by one).

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I will take this as final option because my system is open to a group of people and they can created they images in svg and jpg. I cannot force them to have svg converted to other format before they uploaded to the server. And I just check the server, there is no inkscape installed, they only provide imagemagick but it is not good in converting scalable vector image from one format to other :(

Comment: @user1285419: Are you using the old `latex` (DVI mode) or the modern `pdflatex` (direct PDF output)? The latter doesn't support EPS but PDF for images. Also, ImageMagick might be able to convert SVG to PDF as long Ghostscript is installed, too.

Comment: hi Martin, I am using texlive 2009 and pdflatex to generate PDF directly. I try imagemagick (with ghostscript installed) to convert svg to pdf. It looks just ok but it seems that the pdf generated was not scalable vector image. I see the raster when I zoom the pdf in. I am wondering if it is due to the imagemagick or it is common to all kind of conversion program to lose the scalable feature while converting svg to eps/pdf. But if there is no better way, I probably will go with this scheme.

Comment: There is `svg` package which does this.

Comment: Hi Harish, I tried the svg package. That's what others discussed in other post about including svg directly in latex. But as shown in the doc and example, it need the additional pdf_tex so to insert into the latex. It doesn't work directly to general svg.

Comment: If inkscape is not available, you can use `cairosvg` (a python script) to convert SVG to PDF (with minimal rasterization).